# Oracle entity framework code first datetime is generated as date instead of timestamp

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When creating a new datetime field via Entity Framework code first and after Add-Migration / update-database, it is generated as DATE instead of TIMESTAMP. How can I make sure this is being generated as TIMESTAMP in Oracle?